# Why does a DC motor like the 775 start jumping when connected to a 24 V, 5 A SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, motor, switch-mode-power-supply

I am making a project in which I am using a 775 DC motor. To run the motor I am using an old laptop charger rated 19 V, 3-4 A maybe. I tried to make it more clear and bought a 24 V, 5A SMPS, but when connected to the 775 motor, the motor starts jumping continuously.

Comment: What does *jumping* mean? Is there any mechanical load on the motor?

Comment: Sounds like OCP hiccup. Observe the voltage output with your scope and report back.

Answer (score 4):

[The motor has a stall (starting/inrush) current of 24.5A](https://ca.robotshop.com/products/775-dc-motor-high-speed-big-torque-24v-8300-rpm). I speculate that the current limiting on your power supplies may be shutting down the power supply and restarting it. You need a power supply that will provide a constant current when it limits. You don't necessarily need a 24.5 amp supply, but you need one that switches to a constant current mode during start-up.

When a power supply goes into current limit its voltage can go to zero., if the control electronics is on the same supply, then the whole system shuts down. Be certain that the electric motor is on its own power suppy.

[image]

Comment: You might be able to add a large capacitor across the power supply to handle the surge current, although you may need to limit charging current.

Comment: I would probably connect the motor directly to the pwer supply, then diode isolate the capacitor to provide voltage to the rest of the electronics. This way the surge current can pull the power supply down without discharging the capacitor. More knowledge of the system is required to include this in the answer.

Comment: Without a large capacitor to provide starting current, the overcurrent circuit will probably continue to "motorboat" until it starts running. A simple PWM soft start or an RC circuit on a relay would be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyRdtH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: DC Motor Starter]

This simple circuit will charge a large capacitor with enough energy to start the motor after a delay of about one second.